# Why is the Milky Way called aryamṇáḥ pánthāḥ?

Tags: vedas, vedic-gods

In the Rig Veda, Aryaman is described as the protector of mares, and the Milky Way (***aryamṇáḥ pánthāḥ***) is said to be his path.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryaman

Comment: Some references: RV 1.41, BG 10.29, SB 4.18.18 (I think Aryaman is related to departed ancestors and his path may be related to milky way).

Comment: Could you add some detail to the question about how / where the link between the path to Aryaman and the Milky way is made? The wiki doesn't tell much and this is an interesting concept. It's not something too special since the milky way is visible to the naked eye (and would have been very prominent long ago).

Answer (score 2):

Aryaman  is one of the early Vedic deities.  Ayaman means a ‘devoted friend’ or ‘Gentleman.’  He is the third son of Aditi, the mother of the Adityas. In the RigVeda Aryaman is described as the protector of mares, and the Milky Way (aryamṇáḥ pánthāḥ) is said to be his path. Aryamans royal path is milky way.

> Aryaman Pantha is an expression which occures in Brahmanas. According
>   to Weber it's Milky Way but  according to Hillebrandt is elliptical.

List of the Brahmana Texts which mentions Aryaman Pantha.

- Taitariya Brahmana i ,7,6,6
- Pancavimsa Brahmana XXV 12.3
- Shatapatha brahmana 5.3.1.2

Here is  [**Shatapatha Brahmana 5.3.1.2**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63275.html)   quote.

> For to Bṛhaspati belongs that upper region, and there above lies that
>   path of Aryaman (the sun).

In the footnote of 5.3.2 it's said as follows "Whence the back of that upper region is white, or bright."

Generally Milky Way is also very bright in the night sky.

But according to some [**Books**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=t6TVLlPvuMAC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=Aryaman%20the%20Milky%20way%20in%20taittiriya%20brahmana&source=bl&ots=6nAefyH_6v&sig=w9X4tPq-pytTOfhKKQIqlcdEyj8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjprPnCnYHXAhVEP48KHQrFDncQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=Aryaman%20the%20Milky%20way%20in%20taittiriya%20brahmana&f=false) this is referring to Milky Way ,and as the path of Aryaman.

so it's look's like from the above that the bright path of Aryaman is above Bṛhaspati's path which according to weber is Milky way. May be That's  the reason.

Comment: Could you please mention the rigveda verse which say Aryaman is the protector of mares, and the Milky Way? because I could not find any verse. On the contrary Rigveda says the milky way is one of the arms of God Savitr

Comment: Ok ,I will try to add that and others if found in some time.:)