# who is God Aryaman in vedas?

Tags: vedas, gods, rig-veda, identification-request

May be some of you know about god aryaman really who is he? even god indra has been asked to recieve gifts from him. He is an aditya. In the Rig Veda Aryaman is
described as the protector of
mares, and the Milky Way
(aryamṇáḥ pánthāḥ) is said to be
his path.

source:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryaman

> 23 Indra, whatever deed of might
>   thou hast this day to execute,
>   None be there now to hinder it.
>
> 24 **O Watchful One, may Aryaman
>   the God give thee all goodly things.**
>   May Pūṣan, Bhaga, and the God
>   Karūḷatī give all things fair.

— Rigveda:book 4:hymn30.24

**What are the verses revealing Aryaman?**

**Is god Aryaman present in post-vedic texts?**

Comment: Aryaman is the first Pitr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Milky Way called aryamṇáḥ pánthāḥ?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21678/why-is-the-milky-way-called-aryam%e1%b9%87%c3%a1%e1%b8%a5-p%c3%a1nth%c4%81%e1%b8%a5)

Comment: The milkyway's connection with aryaman is a sub-question here @nog shine.

Comment: @Fiercelord You should remove the parts which are already asked in the previous question and liit your questions to one. .

Comment: These links might be helpful for ur first question: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08047.htm http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01036.htm http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08018.htm

Answer (score 4):

```
Is god Aryaman present in post-vedic texts?
```

**Yes** the god Aryaman is present in Post-Vedic texts like puranas also.

The [**Brahma Purana**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahma-purana/d/doc57563.html)   lists him in twelve  Adityas and describe the sun in the form of Wind as Aryama  -

> As  Aryama he is the wind.

In each month of the year its is different Aditya ( sun who shines.)

> Aryama in Vaishakha.

---

Its  said in **Bhagvat Purana** that in Hiraṇmaya-varṣa Aryama worships Lord vishnu along with other residents.

> हिरण्मयेऽपि भगवान्निवसति कूर्मतनुं बिभ्राणस्तस्य तत्प्रियतमां | 
>   तनुमर्यमा सह वर्षपुरुषैः पितृगणाधिपतिरुपधावति मन्त्रमिमं चानुजपति ||
>   5.18.29||
>
> hiraṇmaye ’pi bhagavān nivasati kūrma-tanuṁ bibhrāṇas tasya tat
>   priyatamāṁ 
>  tanum **aryamā** saha varṣa-puruṣaiḥ pitṛ-gaṇādhipatir
>   upadhāvati mantram imaṁ cānujapati.
>
> Śukadeva Gosvāmī continued: In Hiraṇmaya-varṣa, the Supreme Lord,
>   Viṣṇu, lives in the form of a tortoise [kūrma-śarīra]. **This most
>   dear and beautiful form is always worshiped there in devotional
>   service by Aryamā, the chief resident of Hiraṇmaya-varṣa,** along with
>   the other inhabitants of that land. They chant the following
>   hymns.[**SB 5.18.29**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/18/29)

It also said in the same Purana that **Aryama is predominating deity of that planet Pitṛloka**

> वत्सेन पितरोऽर्यम्णा कव्यं क्षीरमधुक्षत ।
>  आमपात्रे महाभागाः
>   श्रद्धया श्राद्धदेवताः ॥14.18. 8॥
>
> vatsena pitaro 'ryamṇā kavyaḿ kṣīram adhukṣata
>  āma-pātre
>   mahā-bhāgāḥ śraddhayā śrāddha-devatāḥ
>
> The fortunate inhabitants of Pitrloka, who preside over the funeral
>   ceremonies, made Aryama into a calf. With great faith they milked
>   kavya, food offered to the ancestors, into an unbaked earthen pot.
>
> **Footnote** - Those who are interested in family welfare are called pitṛ-vratāḥ. There is a planet called Pitṛloka, and the predominating
>   deity of that planet is called Aryamā.[**SB 4.18.18**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/18/18)

---

```
Discribe the connection of aryaman with milkyway?
```

The answer of this  is already present here. You can read it  in this  [**answer**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21695) of mine

---

```
What are the verses revealing Aryaman?
```

Here are some of the verses revealing Aryaman. He is not praised separately  or independently in vedas but often with Mitra and Varuna.

> नु मित्रो वरुणो अर्यमा नत्स्मने तोकाय वरिवो  दधन्तु  |
>  सुगा नो
>   विश्वा सुपथानि सन्तु  यूयं  पात स्वस्तिम्भि : सदा न || 7.63.6 ||
>
> Now Mitra, Varuṇa, **Aryaman vouchsafe us freedom and room, for us and
>   for our children.** May we find paths all fair and good to travel.
>   Preserve us evermore, ye Gods, with blessings. [**RV 7.63.6**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07063.htm)
>   Ralph T.H. Griffith and here is [**Hindi**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.80)  Hindi translation.
>
> ---
>
> वि ये दधु: शरदं मासमाद्हर्यज्ञमक्तुं चाद्रुचमम् | 
>  अनाप्यं वरुणो
>   मित्रो अर्यमा क्षत्रं राजान आशत  ||RV 7.66.11||
>
> **They who have stablished year and month and then the day**, night, sacrifice and holy verse, Varuṇa, Mitra, Aryarnan, the Kings, have won
>   dominion which none else may gain. [**RV 7.66.11**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07066.htm) Ralph T.H.
>   Griffith and here is [**Hindi**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.82) translation.

---

Here are some of the additional mantras of Aryama from Rig-Veda.
[**RV 7.59.1**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.74)
[**RV 7.60.5-6**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.76)
[**RV 7.61.8**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.77)

The Rig-Vedic verses Praising Aryama with Mitra-Varuna for welfare of self with rest of family members.

It says let our progny get the good wealth ,let our path of progress be easy. Let we and our family be well nourished by the grace of Aryama.